# MySQL Join on 3 tables returns just one value

Tags: mysql

I have the following 4 tables set up in MySQL. I want to be able to output data certain bits of data from all of them using joins, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
TABLE books
 ---------------------------
| id |         name         |
 ---------------------------
| 1  |   War of the Worlds  |
| 2  |  The Treasure Island |
| 3  |      The Hobbit      |
| 4  |     Friend or Foe    |
 ---------------------------

TABLE users
 --------------
| id |   name  |
 --------------
| 1  |  Alfie  |
| 2  |   Ben   |
| 3  | Charlie |
| 4  |   Doug  |
 --------------

TABLE library
 -------------------
| user_id | book_id |
 -------------------
|    1    |    1    |
|    1    |    3    |
|    1    |    4    |
|    1    |    5    |
|    2    |    2    |
|    4    |    4    |
 -------------------

TABLE reviews
 ------------------
| book_id | rating |
 ------------------
|    1    |    4   |
|    1    |    3   |
|    1    |    4   |
|    3    |    5   |
|    4    |    1   |
|    4    |    3   |
|    4    |    1   |
 ------------------
```

I have tried using the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT
library.user_id,
users.name,
library.book_id,
books.name,
COUNT(reviews.book_id)
FROM library
JOIN users
    ON users.id = library.user_id
JOIN books
    ON books.id = library.book_id
LEFT JOIN reviews
    ON reviews.book_id = books.id
WHERE library.user_id = 1;
```

I want the output to be something along the lines of:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id | users.name | book_id |     books.name    | COUNT |
 ------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |    Alfie   |    1    | War of the Worlds |   3   |
|    1    |    Alfie   |    3    |     The Hobbit    |   1   |
|    1    |    Alfie   |    4    |   Friend or Foe   |   3   |
 ------------------------------------------------------------
```

But all I get with my query is:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id | users.name | book_id |     books.name    | COUNT |
 ------------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |    Alfie   |    1    | War of the Worlds |   7   |
 ------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm sorry if this sounds really stupid because I'm probably just being dumb but I've been playing around for ages now and I can't understand a thing so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much for your time.

P.S. Apologies for the crappy formatting, I've tried to make it as easy as possible :)

Comment: Try changing all the `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using count, Try to group the query based on user_id, name, book_id, book_name

```
SELECT
library.user_id,
users.name,
library.book_id,
books.name,
COUNT(reviews.book_id)
FROM library
JOIN users
ON users.id = library.user_id
JOIN books
ON books.id = library.book_id
LEFT JOIN reviews
ON reviews.book_id = books.id
WHERE library.user_id = 1
group by library.user_id,users.name, library.book_id, books.name
```